# How to skip multiple intents smoothly

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which has a flow like this Intro-Slider Activity --> Login/Register Activity --> Dashboard Activity.

Now the intro slider will be displayed for only once and if the user has successfully logged in it will go directly to the dashboard until he logs out. So there is a bit **delay** of 2 sec(I guess it will increase in slower devices , mine Redmi 1S) if the user launches the app for the 2nd time with successfully logged in.

Is there any way to reduce this delay?

**N.B:** Currently I'm not using any flags to launch the intents.

Comment: Check out for business logic's that you are doing other than UI main thread updates. If you could move these to worker thread your UI should perform well

Comment: Are u proposing of a loading intent in the beginning , then all this work in background ? @Stallion